Dictionary Update Stops at Index 35
I'm trying to iterate through a list (config_patterns) and add each element as a key to a dictionary (predefined_patterns) with a value of 0. There are 40 elements in this list. However, the final dictionary only contains elements up to a specific index 35. The remaining elements in the list are missing from the dictionary.
Expected Behavior: The predefined_patterns dictionary should contain all elements from config_patterns as keys, each with a value of 0.
Additional Information:

I've confirmed that config_patterns is a list of strings (no hashable issues)
I've verfied that the loop iterates through the expected number of elements
No modification are happening to config_patterns within the loop

Things I've tried:

Using update method instead of direct assignment
Checking for hidden modifications or asynchronous operations


Your list must contain four duplicates

Duplicate Dictionary keys are overwritten.

Print len(set(config_patterns))

Your config_patterns list contains duplicates. You can verify that by converting the list to a set, which only contains unique records, and printing its size. Note the additional line below print(len(config_patterns)):
config_patterns = ['.//FunctionDef/body//If', './/FunctionDef/body//If[ancestor::If and not(parent::orelse)]', './/FunctionDef[@name="__init__"]/body/Return', './/FunctionDef//Compare/left[@id="input_dirs"]/following-sibling::Compare/ops/NotEq | .//FunctionDef//Compare/comparators[@id="input_dirs"]/following-sibling::Compare/ops/NotEq', './/FunctionDef//Try/ExceptHandler[not(ExceptHandler/type)]', './/FunctionDef//Compare/ops/Is | .//FunctionDef//Compare/ops/Eq', './/FunctionDef[not(args/arg/annotation) or not(returns)]', './/FunctionDef//Call/func/Attribute[@attr="keys"]', './/FunctionDef/body/Assign/value/Dict/keys/Name[preceding-sibling::Name/@id = @id]', './/FunctionDef[./body/Assert/test/Tuple]', './/FunctionDef/body/For[target/Name/@id = iter/Name/@id]', './/FunctionDef[body//comprehension/target/Name]', './/FunctionDef//FunctionDef/ancestor::*', './/FunctionDef//If/following-sibling::If | .//FunctionDef//If/following-sibling::Elif | .//FunctionDef//If/following-sibling::Else', './/FunctionDef//If/descendant::If', './/FunctionDef//if//For', './/FunctionDef[//(If/following-sibling::For | For/following-sibling::If)]', './/FunctionDef//For[.//For]', './/FunctionDef/body/Assert', './/FunctionDef[starts-with(@name, "test_")]/body/*', './/FunctionDef/body/* | .//FunctionDef/body/Return', './/FunctionDef[starts-with(@name, "test_")]//Assert[count(.//Call[func/Name/@id="test_function"]) > 0]', './/FunctionDef//*[starts-with(., "with open")]', './/FunctionDef[count(body//Return) > 2]', './/FunctionDef//BinOp[count(descendant::BinOp) > 2]', '//FunctionDef[starts-with(@name, "test_")]//Assert[count(.//Call[func/Name]) > 0]', './/FunctionDef[count(./body/*) > 50]', './/FunctionDef[count(.//If | .//For | .//While | .//And | .//Or) > 10]', './/FunctionDef[count(./args/args) > 5]', './/Call[count(./func/Attribute) > 3]', './/FunctionDef[count(.//If | .//For | .//While | .//Try) > 3]', './/FunctionDef[count(./body/*) > 100]', './/ExceptHandler[not(./body/*)]', './/Num', './/Global', './/ClassDef[count(./body/*) > 50]', './/FunctionDef[count(./args/args) > 5]', './/FunctionDef[count(./body/*) > 50]', './/Call[count(./func/Attribute) > 3]', './/FunctionDef[count(.//If | .//For | .//While | .//Try) > 3]']

count = 0
predefined_patterns= {}
print(len(config_patterns))
print(len(set(config_patterns)))

for pattern in list(config_patterns):
    predefined_patterns[pattern] = 0
    count += 1

print(f"Number of iterations: {count}")

print()
i = 0
for key,value in predefined_patterns.items():
    print(f"{i}. {key}:{value}")
    i = i+1

This will show that there are only 36 unique entries in the list (of 40 total entries), hence why your dictionary only contains 36 entries.

And the duplicates are the last 4 elements
.//FunctionDef[count(./args/args) > 5]
.//FunctionDef[count(./body/*) > 50]
.//Call[count(./func/Attribute) > 3]
.//FunctionDef[count(.//If | .//For | .//While | .//Try) > 3]
